# Set equality, help needed

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove the following:

[image]

[image]

Any hints on what should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \notin B$ and $x \in C$ imply that $x \notin B \cap C$. Hence, you have $x \in A \cap C$ and $x \notin B \cap C$, and so $x \in (A \cap C) - (B \cap C)$.

Comment: thanks, that makes perfect sense? I have posted the rest of the solution, which is proving the other side. Is it okay for me to ignore them?

Comment: @Aaron you should get that $(x \in A) \wedge (x \notin B) \wedge (x \in C)$, from which you get $x \in (A-B) \cap C$.

Comment: yes I get it. But if I can ignore that term, I would end up getting $(x∈A)∧(x∉B)∧(x∈C)$ right? Am I able to do so, because it is logical OR?

Comment: yup, you're right